# AngularJS observe directive attribute expressions, inherit scope dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, expression

My code is as simple:

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.x = 5;
    }, 2000);
  }])
.directive('ngHey', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
      'restrict': 'A',
      'scope': true,
      'link': function($scope, el, atr) {

        var go = function () {
            if ($parse(atr.ngHey)()) {

              alert('oiiiiiii');
            }
          };

        atr.$observe('ngHey', function (val) {
          if (val) {

            go();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

//view.html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<span ng-hey="x > 3"></span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to fire when directive expression changes and when it's true or false, but at the moment the alert never happen...

It works only if i do something like:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span ng-hey="{{x > 3}}"></span>
    </div>
```

which is not what i would like, i would like the directive to execute expressions as for ng-if or ng-hide etc...

Any tip or help appreciated,
thanks

Comment: scope.$eval(atr.ngHey)

Comment: @mohamedrias tried, just replaced $scope.$eval(atr.ngHey)(); on $parse(atr.ngHey); but it seems not firing when expression becomes true

Comment: I've updated in answer. Please check there :)

Comment: @mohamedrias checked i appreciated but $watch means static variables, i need scope vars to be dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `$observe` in this case, as it `Observes an interpolated attribute.` ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)). In this case you can use `$watch` on the scope like this:

```
.directive('ngHey', ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
        return {
            scope: true,
            link: function($scope, el, atr) {

                var go = function(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        alert('oiiiiiii');
                    }
                };

                $scope.$watch(atr.ngHey, function(val) {
                    if (val) {
                        go(val);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XakjA2I7lpJdo9YAZFEH?p=preview

**UPD.** Based on the OP's comments, updated directive looks like:

```
.directive('ngHey', ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
        return {
            scope:{ngHey: '='},
            link: function($scope, el, atr) {

                var go = function(value) {
                    if ($scope.ngHey) {
                        alert('oiiiiiii');
                    }
                };

                $scope.$watch('ngHey', function(val) {
                    if (val) {
                        go();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Note, how you can use `$scope.ngHey` in this case, not need to `$eval` attribute.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XakjA2I7lpJdo9YAZFEH?p=preview

Comment: hi, i think i fixed all, and yeah you are right for me, i used watch instead of observe and then replaced $parse with **$scope.$parent.$eval(atr.ngHey)**

Comment: if you would add also my changes to your answer i will accept , thank you

Comment: oh and i forgot instead of scope:true i added *scope:{ngHey:'='}*

Comment: You don't really need `$scope.$parent.$eval(atr.ngHey)` if you have `scope:{ngHey:'='}`. You can simply use `$scope.ngHey` it will be the same but cleaner.

Comment: Check updated answer for new version of the directive.

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neuTA/730/)

As the `$timeout` is setting the value of x later, the condition inside the directive checking for attribute was returning `false` always. So use `$watch` to check the condition in `go()` whenever `x` changes.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('ngHey', function () {
    return {
      'restrict': 'A',
       'scope': true,
      'link': function($scope, el, attr) {

        var go = function () {
            if ($scope.$eval(attr.ngHey)) {
              alert('oiiiiiii');
            }
          };

        $scope.$watch('x', function (val) {
          if (val) {
            go();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Instead of `$parse` use `$scope.$eval` and also similarly  instead of `$observe` use `$watch`.

Comment: Sorry but i can't use $watch, scope variables are dynamic/unknown, is not always scope.x it could be whatever you want/need :)